# Specify network to not backpropagate the gradients in a given function

Tags: python, pytorch

In my neural network, in order to compute the loss, I need to do some intermediate computations during training to first obtain some transformations `rv`.

```
rv = factor.ransac(source, target, prob, device)
predicted = factor.predict(source, rv, outputs, device)
loss = criterion(predicted, target)
```

I want to backpropagate the gradients only through `predicted` but not through `factor.ransac`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [detach()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.detach).

```
rv = factor.ransac(source, target, prob, device).detach()
```

That way, gradients on `rv` will be discarded.